# Google Maps : create (short) URL to current view & location?

Tags: google-maps, geolocation, shortcut

Google Maps used to have a feature to create a link (short URL) to the current view and location. However that doesn't seem to be there anymore...?? Is that gone or how do I do that?

I mean not just a link to a specific search query, i.e. like `maps.google.com/maps?q=<address>` or `maps.google.com/maps?q=<lat,lon>`, but when moving around, having a certain view and zoom level and everything, you could do 'Create link'. With a checkbox 'create short URL` which resulted in URLs like http://goo.gl/maps/AbCdEf.

Anyone knows where I can find that feature now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Left to the search box you'll find the following icon: 
[image]

Here you find the option for sharing the link to the current view, also for short links.

Answer (score 0):

It has changed in the latest version of Maps: If you click on the "Share" Icon in the route details section - it allows the same thing - select "Short URL" and off you go...